# If $H^j(U,\mathcal{F})$ vanishes, stalk of the presheaf of cohomology groups of $\mathcal{F}$ also vanishes at $x \in U$

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

The following statement appears in [these](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/perso/massot.patrick/gdtSS/microsupport.pdf) notes I'm trying to read:
$\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of $R-$modules on a topological space $X$. Corresponding to $\mathcal{F}$ we can construct a presheaf $H^j(\mathcal{F})$ of cohomology groups of $F$ by  $U \mapsto H^j(U,\mathcal{F})$. Consider $x \in X$.
Then,

> If $H^j(U,\mathcal{F})$ vanishes for some neighborhood $U$ of $x$, then the stalk $H^j(\mathcal{F})_x$ vanishes.

It will be enough to show that the restriction maps $H^j(\mathcal{F})(U) \rightarrow H^j(\mathcal{F})(V)$ for open sets $U,V$ of $X, V \subset U$ i.e given any closed section in $\mathcal{I}^j(V)$ I need to lift it to a closed section in $\mathcal{I}^j(U)$, where $0\rightarrow\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{I}^0\rightarrow\mathcal{I}^1...$ is an injective resolution of $\mathcal{F}$. There always exists a lift by flabiness of injective sheaves, but how do I ensure that the lift be closed ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't that immediate that if $H^j(U,\mathcal{F})$ vanishes for some $U$ then $\varinjlim_{U\ni x} H^j(U,\mathcal{F})$ vanishes too ?

Comment: @C. Dubussy Forgive me if this is too trivial, but I still don't get it. Could you explain a bit more. Are you saying that for any presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ if sections on some $U$ are zero the stalks at all points of $U$ are zero ? I can take any sheaf with nonzero stalks and replace global sections by zero.